# What is `_dereq_()` inside React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm searching through `react-0.13.3.js` and one thing I can't work out. At the very start of the source there's a bunch of `dereq()` calls.

```
'use strict';

var EventPluginUtils = _dereq_(19);
var ReactChildren = _dereq_(32);
var ReactComponent = _dereq_(34);
var ReactClass = _dereq_(33);
```

But nowhere do I see an implementation for that function. What does it do and how does it work? And most importantly, where is it declared?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/derequire/issues/25.

Comment: That's the answer right there. If you could write it up, I would accept it :)

Comment: Okay I'll add it to my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely [derequire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/derequire) combined with [browserify](http://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/how-browserify-works/) (or other bundler?) module ids. It's a way to rename `require` in your output bundle so as to avoid collisions.

Read here for more information: https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/derequire/issues/25

The basic idea is that different module loaders handle `require` differently. "Derequire" is a strategy for binding your requires to your context via a different keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with [amd module loader](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api). `_dereq_` is the first argument so it's the `require` function.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it does when I say `var EventPluginUtils = _dereq_(19);`? What does `19` do, is it a way to prioritise something?

Comment: It's the bundle index/id. See for example the `--full-paths` option of browserify: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand `line 4` in the source; it's `require`.

```
1: [function(_dereq_, module, exports) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled on this question, after some research, I think the main purpose of having this function is to build a similar npm like feature on your browser and handle module dependency on importing different functions.

if you go straight to the end of the IIFE  (about 20k~ lines)

you will see a structure similar to below

```
(function e(t, n, r) {
    function s(o, u) {
       ...
    }

       ...
}) ({...  //blah blah blah, all the funcitons 
     }, {}, [1])


the variable t is all the functions modules
the variable n is an empty array
 the variable r is 1 here
```

so the require module is called in the right order, and is built from index 1, from there, it is pretty self-explanatory, all dependencies needs to be correctly programmed from the array on the outset

```
1: [function (_dereq_, module, exports) {....
}, {"106": 106, "23": 23, "35": 35, "45": 45, "63": 63}],
```